# Call a method from panel with no Event in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, controller, components

if some people can help,

The point is i want to load datas in grid inside a panel.
structure is :

```
           view
              /panel
                  /panel.js
```

i would like to know how to call a method linked to this component on init controller with no events in ExtJs :

..

```
init: function(){
          this.control({
        'customerpanelpanel': {

            /**
             * @event customergrid event fired on customer clicked.
             *
             * Exécute la méthode openTab.
             *
             * @param {string} Customer = Chargement des clients
             */
            customergrid: function () {
                this.openTab('Patients'); <!-- this is the call -->
            },
        }
```

When calling this.openTab('Customer') with the Customer panel directly ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `this` isn't `customergrid`. (`this` should point to the anonymous object, but I am not completely sure about that.) This is why Sencha decided that the first parameter to every event should be the component.

For your customergrid event to work, somewhere you have the code.

```
grid.fireEvent('customergrid');
```

You would instead fire it like this:

```
grid.fireEvent('customergrid',grid,customer);
```

and then you can use

```
customergrid: function (grid, customer) {
    grid.openTab('Patients');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a viewcontroller you can do

```
    this                  // the viewcontroller
        .getView()        // the panel
        .myFunctionCall(param1, param2)
```

If not, you can use the ComponentQuery:

```
var myPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('my-custom-panel')[0] // via XType
```

or

```
var myPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#my-custom-panel')[0] // via itemId
```

and then

```
myPanel.myFunctionCall(param1, param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

> When calling this.openTab('Customer') with the Customer panel directly?

You can just call it within controller `init` function, like this:

```
init: function () {
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('customerpanelpanel')[0].openTab('Patients');

    this.control({
    ...
    });
},
```